# how to get the least row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to retrieve the row from Sql Server Table which has the minimum value but that should not change the order of data in the rows, i.e. data next to an Id should not be misordered I am trying to get the results but I am not satisfied with what I get.I know I can use where clause to stop the data from misplacing the order but as I want to relate it to java vectors I cannot use that option.
 Here is what I am currently Coding rm_id is my ID but I am getting everywhere the minimum value that is 0

```
SELECT   b.rm_id AS 'REMITTANCE ID',
     min(b.[1]) AS 'Re. 1',
     min(b.[2]) AS 'Rs. 2',
     min(b.[5]) AS 'Rs. 5',
     min(b.[10]) AS 'Rs. 10',
     min(b.[20]) AS 'Rs. 20',
     min(b.[50]) AS 'Rs. 50',
     min(b.[100]) AS 'Rs. 100',
     min(b.[500]) AS 'Rs. 500',
     min(b.[1000]) AS 'Rs. 1000',
     min(b.[tp]) AS 'T.P',
     min(b.[tv]) AS 'T.V'
FROM     trans_det AS b
GROUP BY b.rm_id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY rm_id DESC;
```

Comment: Your question is vague.  You say you want the row with them minimum value, but you don't specify a field for which this minimum value should apply.  Another consideration is that there might be a tie, so you need to know how to handle that.

Comment: We cannot understand what you want.  Please add some sample data and the results that you like to see from that data.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might want this instead:

```
select top 1 td.* from trans_det order by b.[1] union all
select top 1 td.* from trans_det order by b.[2] union all
select top 1 td.* from trans_det order by b.[5] union all
. . .
select top 1 td.* from trans_det order by b.tv
```

This will return the set of rows with a minimum for each value.